# Filter RDD[(VertexId,(VertexId, String, String))] in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an origin RDD:

```
var userNodesRdd = usersGraph.vertices.asInstanceOf[RDD[(VertexId,(VertexId, String, String))]]
userNodesRdd.foreach(println) // check
/* I see:
* (533,[533,fobi,m])
* (610,[610,pablo,m])
* (627,[627,marco,m])
* (571,[571,anna,f])
* (590,[590,luca,m])
*
```

And I want to obtain from it, an RDD with only the elements that verify a condition (only those who have this aspect `( _ , [ _ , _ , m]) )`. 
For this goal I'm using this:

```
var maleUserNodesRdd = userNodesRdd.filter{
  case (_,(_,_,gender)) => gender == "m"
}
maleUserNodesRdd.foreach(println)
```

but I obtain:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple3
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Value in your code is `Row` object, not `Tuple3`, so you should use `Row` in the pattern:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val maleUserNodesRdd = userNodesRdd.filter{
   case (_, Row(_, _, gender)) => gender == "m"
}
```

at the same time:

```
asInstanceOf[RDD[(VertexId,(VertexId, String, String))]]
```

is not valid just keep

```
var userNodesRdd = usersGraph.vertices
```